# Dynamic Visualforce Components with commandButtons tied to records

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, commandbutton, dynamic-binding

I'm creating a VisualForce page that is going to load records from a web service using JSON.

I have a requirement to add a button next to each record I pull. I don't see a direct way to do this with Dynamic Visualforce Components (unless I missed something). Can you bind and display a button for each record dynamically?

The button is going to load an object new record page using the values corresponding to the button bindings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an [ApexPages.Action](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_action.htm) on your parent controller/page to pass to your components.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on your data structure, if you insert the data before, or what but you can use the following to get you close

I find it simpler in these case to just use html / javascript

Using a repeat to display the records:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!yourrecords}" var="r">

 ..row of data ...<button onclick="window.open('/{!r.id}')">Button Text</button>

</apex:repeat>
```

Of course this is not the be all end all solution but it is one way to do it